# Por qué en el siguiente código hay un puntero en un campo de bits?

Tags: c++, c

Tengo una duda sobre una biblioteca CMSIS que descargue para una KL25Z, en la cual encontré un campo de bits que tiene un puntero. Cosa que yo nunca he visto y no le veo el sentido. El código es el siguiente...

```
struct SIM_SCGC5_REG{union {
__IO uint32_t             all;
struct {
  __IO uint32_t LPTMR       : 1;
       uint32_t RESERVED0   : 4;
  __IO uint32_t TSI         : 1;
       uint32_t RESERVED1   : 3;
  __IO uint32_t PORTA       : 1;
  __IO uint32_t PORTB       : 1;
  __IO uint32_t PORTC       : 1;
  __IO uint32_t PORTD       : 1;
  __IO uint32_t PORTE       : 1;
       uint32_t RESERVED2   : 18;
};};};
```

y por ejemplo PORTB esta definido así...

```
#define PORTB       (( PORT_TypeDef *)        PORTB_BASE)
```

Este es el link para que tengan una mayor perspectiva.
https://github.com/bharrisau/cmsis-freescale

Agradecería mucho su tiempo para que me aclaren mi duda de por qué pasa esto :)

Comment: Eso no puede ser. Dentro de `struct SIM_SCGC5_REG`, `PORTB` es **el nombre** del campo. Cualquier cosa que no sea un identificador válido directamente **no compila**; osea, que no puedes poner ahí eso que dices. Te has confundido de alguna forma.

Comment: Yo solo veo campos de tipo `uint32_t`. ¿Puedes ser más claro?